HTMX: Sending POST Requestbody
I have an HTML in which I want to call an endpoint via HTMX and pass a request body along with it. I don't want to use explit FORM, but define a button in HTML as follows:
<button
  id="executeButton"
  class="..."
  hx-post="/doSomething"
  hx-vals='js: {
            "type": "type",
            "param1": "param1"
         }'
  hx-target="#result"
  hx-swap="innerHTML"
>
  <span class="g-btn-text">Execute</span>
</button>;

By default, HTMX does not seem to forward the request as application/json. I found the only variant that works like this in the following description
https://www.submitjson.com/blog/htmx-post-json
This means that if I define the button in the following way (enhancing it with hx-ext) and specify the corresponding script, the request body is forwarded correctly as JSON:
<button id="executeButton" class="..."
    hx-post="/doSomething"
    **hx-ext="postrequestbody"**  
    hx-vals='js: {
        "type": "type",
        "param1": "param1"
        }'
    hx-target="#result"
    hx-swap="innerHTML"
>
                        
    <span class="g-btn-text">Execute</span>
</button>

... 
<script>
    htmx.defineExtension('postrequestbody', {
        onEvent: function (name, evt) {
            if (name === "htmx:configRequest") {
                evt.detail.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
                evt.detail.headers['X-API-Key'] = 'sjk_xxx'
            }
        },
        encodeParameters: function(xhr, parameters, elt) {
            xhr.overrideMimeType('text/json') // override default mime type
            return (JSON.stringify(parameters))
        }
    });
</script>

But:
My problem now is that I want to execute the code not from HTML but dynamically in a Javascript file. HTMX offers htmx.ajax for this purpose, so I tried something like this:
try {
    htmx.ajax('POST', url, {
        target: target,
        swap: 'innerHTML'
    });
} catch (htmxError) {
    // Handle errors from HTMX
    console.error('HTMX error:', htmxError);
}

But apparently not all attributes (e.g. hx-ext) are supported.
Does anyone know what to do? I.e. how can I send the HTMX call via Javascript so that I can include the request body in the POST?
Basically, we have a spring boot controller that returns a thymeleaf fragment into a container div. The returned fragment contains both: HTML tags and imports for javascript (stored in files). The controller has to be executed via POST since we have to send additional data in the requestbody. And here is the problem:
HTMX has problems when you execute POST using requestbody as described above since it automatically sets the content type to
application/x-www-form-urlencoded. We tried differend scenarios, eg. setting the content type explecitely or writing interceptors in spring boot to change the content type before the controller is executed - but nothing works.
We also tried to execute the controller using a regular fetch request (i.e., set via innerHTML) - but than the Javascript are not executed.
However, if I use HTMX swap, the scripts are executed correctly.
As mentioned above: There is already a workaround using hx-ext.
But since we're working on a factorry that shoud create html/hatmx components dynamically we have to execute the htmx using jaascript. And here the x-attributes are not supported (see code above)
So the question is: How can we execute a htmx-ajax call using POST and requestbody (since hx-ext does not work here)
Or: If somoe knows a way to do a regular fetch and reinsert the HTML/Javascript into the DOM, that would also be very helpful

Can you say more about why you want to do it dynamically now?  This will help us to understand the constraints.  But my initial thought is that if you only need to do it dynamically in that JS, then you don't need to mess with an extension; i.e., can you get away with doing something like this? https://hayageek.com/htmx-ajax-post-json-fileupload-example/

Hi Brian, I described a little bit more in detail our scenario, hope this helps

In EHTML you can just wrap with e-form and add you hidden input fields or <e-form-dynamic-value> to bind values, it will be more readable.
